# Handle various groups of users' profiles with django-userena

Tags: django

I have successfully implemented a way to create users belonging to different groups with userena using a different form for each signup url, inheriting the userena signup form and overriding the save method to include the user to a group or another.

For instance in my /brands/ urls I have:

```
url(r'^signup/$',
'userena.views.signup',
{'template_name': 'userena/signup_form_brands.html', 'signup_form': SignupFormBrands}
),
```

and in that form I have:

```
from userena.forms import SignupForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group


class SignupFormBrands(SignupForm):

def save(self):
    # First save the parent form and get the user.
    new_user = super(SignupFormBrands, self).save()
    new_user.groups.add(Group.objects.get(name='Brands'))
    return new_user
```

So I got what I needed with the batteries included in userena. But now I would like to keep using the included profile editing / viewing capabilities of userena but with 2 different kinds of profiles. I would like to create 2 different profile models, one for my default users and one for the brands. Then I want userena to be able to edit the right kind of profile model according to the user belonging to a group or another. I'm not sure how this works and how I could do it.

Edit: userena uses `profile = user.get_profile()`to edit the profile so I'm going to try to assign a different profile object by editing this class.

Comment: Did you succeeded? If yes could you please answer to your question? It may be useful for others ;)

Comment: Sorry @Leonardo I went on using a work around with that one, I don't even remember how I did it, probably quick and dirty. I have no clue :(

Answer (score 0):

you can override  User.get_profile by following code:

```
original_get_profile = User.get_profile
def get_profile(self):
    if getattr(settings, 'AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE', None) != 'profiles.Profile':
        return original_get_profile(self)
    if not hasattr(self, '_profile_cache'):
        self._profile_cache = self.profile
        self.profile.user = self
    return self._profile_cache
User.get_profile = get_profile
```

Put it somewhere in models.py file with your profiles.
code copied from here: http://pastebin.com/MP6bY8H9